# Samba does not show all ZFS snapshots

Tags: samba, zfs, file-server

I am setting up a file server that uses Samba together with ZFS.
I have configured Samba such that it shows the ZFS snapshots under "Previous Versions" in Windows; following is an excerpt of my Samba config:

```
vfs objects = acl_xattr shadow_copy2
shadow:snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
shadow:format = -%Y-%m-%d-%H%M
shadow:snapprefix = ^zfs-auto-snap_\(frequent\)\{0,1\}\(hourly\)\{0,1\}\(daily\)\{0,1\}\(monthly\)\{0,1\}
shadow:delimiter = -20
```

Further, I have configured `zfs-auto-snapshot` (https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs-auto-snapshot/tree/master) and now, I can see the "Previous Versions" of any folder in Windows Explorer:

[image]

However, when I want to see the previous versions of an ordinary file, that doesn't work:

[image]

I wonder how I shall change my Samba configuration such that I can see the previous versions of files as well. I believe this is possible, but I don't know how.

I am using Fedora 38 and Samba Version 4.18.6.